# RF Power measured using near field probe

Tags: rf, near-field

I'm trying to measure the TX signal strength of an intentional transmitter at 2.4 GHz.  I'm using a near field probe and can clearly see the signal, but the amplitude is less than I was expecting - it's negative dBm when I was expecting around 15 dBm.
Is this a result of loses due to the near field probe?  I have heard they are not always accurate.
Or am I interpreting the measurement wrong?

[image]

Comment: We need more information on the near field probe and your setup.  These kinds of measurements, like receive sensitivity, are, are very difficult to make correctly.

Comment: A near-field probe will only measure the intensity in the direction it is being use and, given that the probe might just sniff a small fraction of the emission then it's impossible to say what is actually going on. Plus if you bring the near-field probe close to the antenna it may detune it.

Comment: dBm is a unit of power, i.e. signal strength. What the near field probe senses is field strength. What the near field probe transmits to your analyser is a signal which also has a signal strength (in dBm), but there must be some constant relating the field strength to the probe's signal strength. Do you know what that constant is?

Comment: When you say "I was expecting 15dBm" what is that? Is that the amount of power you expected your near-field probe to measure? How did you come to that number?